# Is it possible to download more styles of widgets in android studio or how do you design your own?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, widget

I have tried looking for information on this but cant seem to find any? Could someone point me in the right direction, thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about layout widgets.

Comment: Is there a numericupdown like in .net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such downloadable package.You either have to create a view or you can get one from open source apps.If you are searching for a specfic view then you can create your own by defining a new of extending a default view class.